# WebElement.click() opens new tab instead of working in same tab

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I stuck with strange problem using testng+selenium webdriver in Firefox.
I have a test which works with dataprovider. First run of test works correctly. In the end of test i navigate to previous page to make second run work correctly. But on second run WebElement.click() opens windown in **NEW TAB** instead of **THE SAME TAB**. **And that's why webdriver couldn't find other elements**. Please give any advice how to proceed through this problem!

I tried:
1. Use Thread.Sleep. Thought it would help, but after sleep time new ta still opens
2. Use windows.Handle to switch to new tab. It also doesn't help me, elements are still not found

My code is below (Dataprovider takes data from xml using Sax and this works correctly):

```
package com.epam.training.selenium;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import utils.TestingUtils;
import xmlparser.TestingData;

public class SeleniumTest 
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String mainPage = "https://mail.ru";
    private String inboxPage = "https://e.mail.ru/messages/inbox/?back=1";
    private String loginVal = "seleniumtest";
    private String passwordVal = "Qwerty123";
    private String domainVal = "@inbox.ru";


@BeforeClass
public void startBrowser(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get(mainPage);
}

@Test(groups = "smoke" , priority=1)
public void authTest(){

    WebElement login = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mailbox__login']" ));
    login.sendKeys(loginVal);

    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mailbox__password']"));
    password.sendKeys(passwordVal);

    Select selectDomain = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mailbox__login__domain']")));
    selectDomain.selectByVisibleText(domainVal);

    WebElement authButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='mailbox__auth__button']"));
    authButton.click();

    WebElement logoutLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PH_logoutLink']"));
    boolean expected = true;
    Assert.assertEquals(logoutLink.isDisplayed(), expected);
}


@Test(groups = {"drafts test"}, dependsOnGroups = "smoke", dataProvider = "New letter test data")
public void createNewLetter(TestingData data){


    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement createLetterButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='b-toolbar__left']/div/div/div[2]/div/a")));
    createLetterButton.click();

    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");

    WebElement senderAdress = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='compose__header__content']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/textarea[2]")));

    senderAdress.sendKeys(data.getSenderAdress());

    WebElement senderSubject = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='compose__header__field']"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.sendKeys(senderSubject, data.getSenderSubject()).click().perform();

    WebElement disableInteractionsButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[19]/a/span[1]/span[2]"));
    disableInteractionsButton.click();

    WebElement senderText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[4]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/textarea"));

    builder.moveToElement(senderText).click().keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0061'))
    .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(data.getSenderText()).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(String.valueOf('\u0073')).perform();

    boolean expected = true;
    //      Assert.assertEquals(senderAdress.isDisplayed(), expected);

    WebElement draftsLink = wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='b-toolbar__right']/div/div/div[2]/div[6]/div"));
        }
    });
    expected = true;
    Assert.assertEquals(draftsLink.isEnabled(), expected);
    driver.get(inboxPage); 
    try { 
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {

    }
}


@DataProvider(name = "New letter test data")
public Object[][] getValuesForNewDraft() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    List<TestingData> dataList = TestingUtils.parse();
    return new Object[][]{
        new Object[] {dataList.get(0)},
        new Object[] {dataList.get(1)}
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What are you clicking on with WebDriver (link, button?).
Links might have 'target' attribute that can make browser open the link in new tab/window.

Comment: i mean bout this     WebElement createLetterButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='b-toolbar__left']/div/div/div[2]/div/a")));
    createLetterButton.click();    it's a button on site

Comment: And what is the button handler (js function)?

Comment: I don't know, there is just a link as far as i can see

Answer (score 0):

As per your `xpath` it is link, and the UI showing as a button link. Some of the button links will open as a separate new tab normally. Did you tried that button link click manually? `WebElement.click()` function it just clicks that element, not change that function to open in the same tab or new tab. check it by click manually.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved!**
I had latest Firefox build v.42, that is not fully supported with Selenium.
Installing v.31 of Firefox solved all problems. Thank you for answers!